# How to scrape this web page with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I searched up and down but could not find any solution that would fit for the purpose.

I would like to scrape this page (table)

https://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/usdjpy/forecast

I tried couple of ways but could not get the data scrapped into a table.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url <-"https://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/usdjpy/forecast"
url2 <- getURL(url)
parsed <- htmlParse(url2)
```

Comment: Open up a new tab in Chrome. Open up "Developer Tools" (hunt around in the Chrome menus). Click the "Network" tab there and the "XHR" sub-tab. Navigate to that page. Look at the `xhr` requests. There's a gd chance you can find the data there but the main HTML page also has a large number of base64-encoded JSON data blobs it parses and generates data tables & charts from (and other dynamic content). So you may need to use `splashr` or `seleniumPipes` if you aren't comfortable dissecting & extracting on-page javascript.

Comment: @hrbrmstr ,this will be hard to follow, I will try my best, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try RSelenium.

Navigate your browser to this URL and wait for the elements to load. Try the technique discussed in this answer

[how to check if page finished loading in RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080920/how-to-check-if-page-finished-loading-in-rselenium)

Once complete loading, you can save the html and read with rvest package or choice of your own.